# If application is written in Javascript and Chaincode is written in Go, will it affect anything in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: javascript, transactions, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I already wrote my Chaincode in Go. Next, I want to make an application to invoke transaction. I just wonder if the Chaincode and the application needs to be written in the same language or is it okay if my application is written in Javascript and my Chaincode is written in Go?

Will there be any compatibility problem if we use different language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there won't be a compatibility problem. There is nothing to tie the language a client application is written in to the language a chaincode is written in

Answer (score -1):

No there won't be any issues. Communication between UI application and Blokchain fabric is done via HTTP client. So its totally different entity.

Comment: Communication with Fabric smart contracts is done via gRPC. It is possible to write a REST client app to enable communication from UIs via http, however that is not something which is provided for you.

Comment: @JamesTaylor Could you please reason why you have disagree with my answer? The question was whether we can connect with Fabric network (chaincode written in any language) from UI which is written in any languare. My answer was, "YES" because the communication is done using HTTP. gRPC protocal is used to communicate between endorsing peers and peers.

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, communication with Fabric smart contracts is done via gRPC, not HTTP. It is possible to write REST APIs using the provided SDKs however that is not something which is provided by Fabric. david_k's answer addresses the question without any confusion over HTTP.